# Changing CSS Upon Window Resizing Breaks CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to recreate:

- Open up this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y408c0u9/7/
- Have the tab open 75% of your monitor and run the Fiddle

As you can see your able to increase the size of the grey box by hovering your mouse over it.

- Resize the width of the tab to the smallest it will go (the grey box will disappear)
- Resize back to how it was before and now the CSS :hover will no longer work.

Annoyingly I can fix it buy changing the javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).resize(function(){

        if ($(window).width() < 640) {
            $('.content').css({
                'width': '100%',
                    'left': '0px'
            });
            $('.menu-button img').attr('src', 'test/lines.png').load(function () {
                this.width;
            });
        }
    if ($(window).width() > 640) {
            $('.content').css({
                'width': 'calc(100%-50px)',
                    'left': '50px'
            });
        }

    });//<-- removing this
```

Breaking the code and having an open bracket obviously isn't wanted as a fix and causes problem with the rest of my javascript.

Why does it act differently after changing the css back to exactly what it was using JQuery/Javascript?

Comment: My guess would be that your javascript is overriding your original :hover rule because it loads after your css. I think you need to add a `.on("hover")` function to your code to keep the desired effect.

Comment: That would make sense and I did fix it before by putting the script before the style however it did break my javascript button (not in that code) which is used to cause the same effect as the hover

Comment: If  your second script functions properly, why not just load it separately in its own script file? Just a thought.

Comment: Yes I could do that however I'd like to know why it is happening not how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is when you resize back, this line:

```
$('.content').css({
    'width': 'calc(100%-50px)',
    'left': '50px'
});
```

is setting the class content style to:

```
left: 50px;
width: 100%;
```

The left: 50px is what's breaking the behavior, and since it's a style tag, it will always override the css tags.  If you change this to remove the left when you drag the gray box back over 640px, it will work.  See the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/y408c0u9/8/

However, I would recommend you use media queries in css to do this.  Javascript can be tough to maintain responsive behavior in, and you can do this in css.

Comment: Yes I'm well aware of media queries I just couldn't be bothered to try to use them at the time and thus probably would have saved myself a lot of time. Unfortunately I am unable to test your proposal at this moment in time and instead will have to get back to you to mark as answered tomorrow.

Comment: I have tested this theory and it doesn't appear to work as once the tab is stretched back out again the bar doesn't re-appear because the blue box is still covering it. Just incase you meant the 50px in the calc if I remove that '50px)' then it still doesn't work. I think I shall look into media queries more

Comment: Ah yeah that does indeed, I completely removed them not set them to blank. Although I won't be using it as I have already changed over to media queries but I will mark as answered as you did suggest this.